# Still provide the name of a record while providing a null value

Tags: sql

So the question I am trying to accomplish is:
Create a query that will show the 
name of those charities that have not received a donation yet along with the 
names of those charities that have received a donation.  Include in your output the name of the charity and the 
donation id.

So far I have:

```
/*------------------------
use AuntieB
select name as [Charity]
, coalesce(donationid,'NULL') as donationid
from charity c join donation d
on c.charityid = d.charityid
------------------------*/
Charity               donationid
-------------------- -----------
Helping Hands               1000
Helping Hands               1001
Boy Scouts                  1002
Boy Scouts                  1003
Focus Hope                  1004
Focus Hope                  1005
Fresh Start Charity         1006
St. John Hospital           1007
Helping Hands               1008
Helping Hands               1009
Helping Hands               1010
Helping Hands               1011
St. Jude                    1012

(13 rows affected)
```

While the output I'm supposed to have is:

```
name                 DonationID
-------------------------------
St. Francis Home            NULL
Salvation Army              NULL
LA Angels Traders           NULL
Purple Heart                NULL
St. Raja Home               NULL
Mother Wattles              NULL
Ron McDonald House          NULL
Helping Hands               1000
Helping Hands               1001
Boy Scouts                  1002
Boy Scouts                  1003
Focus Hope                  1004
Focus Hope                  1005
Fresh Start Charity         1006
St. John Hospital           1007
Helping Hands               1008
Helping Hands               1009
Helping Hands               1010
Helping Hands               1011
St. Jude                    1012
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a left outer join

```
use AuntieB
select name as [Charity]
,donationid as donationid
from charity c left outer join donation d
on c.charityid = d.charityid
```

The LEFT OUTER JOIN keyword returns all records from the left table (charity), and the matched records from the right table (donation). The result is NULL from the right side, if there is no match.

Comment: Using this line of code gave me the error of: Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'NULL' to data type int.

Comment: *Yu* is not a word in the English language, and *eft outer join* doesn't exist. You should also make an effort to explain *why* that outer join is needed. There is zero effort here to provide knowledge; this is simply a low-quality code dump.

Comment: if you remove the coalesce statement, and just leave donationid, it should work.

Comment: why that outer join is needed. There is zero effort here to provide knowledge; this is simply a low-quality code dump. – Ken White 4 mins ago